# A variant of the ode $\dot x=y, \dot y=-x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The ordinary differential equation $\dot x(t)=y(t)$ and $\dot y(t)=-x(t)$ clearly has a family of solutions given by
$$
x(t)= r\cos(t), y(t)=-r\sin(t), t\in\mathbb R
$$
Now, let $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be a positive smooth function. I want to study a modified differential equation system
$$
\dot x=f(x^2+y^2) \cdot y \\
\dot y=-f(x^2+y^2) \cdot x
$$
We cannot find explicit solutions, but I was wondering if we could still prove that there exist solutions for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Shouldn't you just get $x(t) = r\cos(f(r^2)t), y(t)=r\sin(f(r^2)t)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}{(r^2)}=\frac{d}{dt}{(x^2+y^2)}=2x\dot{x}+2y\dot{y}=f(r^2)\left(2xy-2yx\right)=0,
$$
so each solution still lies at a constant radius... the only difference between this and the original equation is that the frequency of the motion now varies with $r$.  You can easily compute $\omega(r)$ in terms of $f$.